# Explain the existence of limit in Persistence Excitation -- mostly zero and non-existent?

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, signal-processing, system-identification

**Definitions**

> Persistence Excitation on page 121 [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53539958/26/Persistent-excitation) or shortly [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmeJv.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkYEs.png). A signal is PE if this limit exists 
>   $$r_u(\tau)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac 1 N \sum_{t=1}^{N} u(t+\tau)u^T(t)$$
>
> And it is of order $n$ if some condition for unknown matrix $R_u(\tau)$ is satisfied. I cannot understand this part of the definition, more in comments.

**How can the limit exist with the PE? If it does, why is it not always zero with most signals? Could someone open the examples a bit to show the non-zero limits? What is the difference between capital $R$ and small $r$?**

**Observations**

> - This article [here](http://jitkomut.lecturer.eng.chula.ac.th/ee531/signal.pdf) states that ARMA processes are PE of any finite order.
> - My university defines PE in terms of the spectrum: if the condition $\Phi(t)>0$ for the spectrum $\Phi(\omega)$ of the signal $u(t)$ almost evewhere in the range $(-\pi, \pi)$, then $u(t)$ is continuously PE -- source [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQxhw.png).

Comment: There's no order in your definition.

Comment: @joriki I haven't yet understood the notation particularly the (ii) part with $R_u(\tau)$ in comparison to $r_u(\tau)$. This is how I understand it -- a signal is PE if the limit exist. And it is of some order $n$ if some other condition $n$ is satisfied but cannot understand the notation differente with capital $R$ and small $r$ -- perhaps misunderstanding the definition.

Comment: @hhh: can you visit the Tagging room and answer some questions about (system-identification)?